# Show or prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \mathrm{e}^{i \alpha x} \mathrm{d}x = \pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, complex-integration

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \mathrm{e}^{i \alpha x} \mathrm{d}x = \pi$$
This particular integral rings a bell in our department(Mathematics). It has yet been solved and proved and keeps showing in every third year Complex Analysis Exam.

An additional condition is that $\alpha$ is real. Assume $\alpha$ is 1, Matlab says the answer is $\pi$ but doesn't say how. Could anyone show me the proof?

Comment: That problem should we written like: Find $$\lim_{\alpha\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} e^{i \alpha x} \,dx.$$ Instantly many would say the limit is $0$ due to the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\expo{\ic\alpha x}\,\dd x} =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\half\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{-\ic kx}
\,\dd k}\expo{\ic\alpha x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\pi\int_{-1}^{1}\dd k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-\ic\pars{k - \alpha}x}
\,{\dd x \over 2\pi} =
\pi\int_{-1}^{1}\delta\pars{k - \alpha}\,\dd k
= \pi\,\Theta\pars{1 - \verts{\alpha}}
\end{align}
However, when $\ds{\verts{\alpha} = 1}$ we can work it out directly from the initial integral as
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\expo{\pm\ic x}\,\dd x=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{2x} \over 2x}\,\dd x = {\pi \over 2}
$$
Then,
$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\expo{\ic\alpha x}\,\dd x
=\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{ccl}
0 & \mbox{if} & \verts{\alpha} > 1
\\[2mm]
\pi  & \mbox{if} & \verts{\alpha} < 1
\\[2mm]
{\pi \over 2}  & \mbox{if} & \alpha = \pm 1
\end{array}\right.\,,\qquad\qquad\alpha\ \in\ {\mathbb R}}
$$

Comment: Ah, finally somebody gets it.

Comment: @Xrobot Dirac delta is always very useful.

Comment: I wonder if it was still possible to solve it using Laplace transforms?

Answer (score 3):

$\sin(x)/x$ is roughly the Fourier transform of a box function, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function#Fourier_transform_of_the_rectangular_function

Then using the convolution theorem this integral is just the convolution of a box function (of width $\pi$ and height $1$) with the constant $1$ function, which is the result.

Answer (score 0):

As $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ is even then
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm{e}^{iax}\,dx=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\cos ax\,dx=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (a+1)x-\sin(a-1)x}{2x}\,dx. \tag{1}
$$
Now for $b>0$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin bx}{x}\,dx\,\,\stackrel{y=bx}=\,\, 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin y}{y}\,dy,
$$
while for $b<0$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin bx}{x}\,dx=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx.
$$
Hence $(1)$ provides
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm{e}^{iax}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}
\big(\sgn(a+1)-\sgn(a-1)\big)
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}
\big(\sgn(a+1)-\sgn(a-1)\big).
$$